# Handlebars.js and multiple templates

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have a scenario in which I am receiving a json formatted array of objects from the server and I need to load varying handlebars templates based on the content type of the object being passed back. For example, my site is made up of multiple blocks of content and those blocks vary in the way in which they are displayed. So I will have one block that is one width and contains different content than another block which may be a different width and contains an entirely different kind of content that needs to be styled in a different way. I would like to use handlebars so that I am not building out a whole bunch of html with js and then inserting it into the DOM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have control over the response coming from the server, on page load, you could precompile your templates into a javascript object, keyed by the heuristic you are using to determine the appropriate template to use for the JS object. 
Then use that mapping to render the template when you receive your data.

How you preload this template mapping and do the rendering depends on what JS libs you are using (if any).

If you provide more details of your templates, the data, and environment some code might be able to be provided.

Comment: I was able to use ajax to call my external handlebars templates and I have a function that places those templates in an object with the keys being the template ids and the templates as the values. Late when compiling I am able to grab the correct template and populate it. Thanks for the response.